# Rails - Combining a Date from a f.select and a Time from a f.time_select into a DateTime column. Sqlite3 DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Here is the error I am receiving.

```
  1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [3, 3] to backup (Missing Parameter - backup(1))]
```

Here is my code.

```
<% @days = [] %>
<% 6.downto(0).each do |number| %>
<% @days << number.days.ago.to_date %>
<% end %>
<%= f.select :backup, @days.collect { |d| [ Date::DAYNAMES[d.wday], d ] } %><br>
<%= f.time_select :backup, :ignore_date => true %><br>
```

Currently in the f.select field, I can choose a day name from the last 6 days and the value would be the actual date that is inserted into the DB. I don't see a way to select the day names as I currently am doing if I were to use f.datetime_select.

Can anyone please explain why this error is coming up?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `datetime_select` straight away?

```
<%= f.datetime_select(:backup, :ampm => true, :start_year => 2000, :end_year => 2025, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :default => { :hour => 00, :minute => 00 }) %>
```

You could also do

```
<%= f.datetime_select(:backup, :ampm => true, default: 6.days.ago) %>
```

If you want the start to be 6 days ago.

Your DB should support the `datetime` format as well.

Comment: Currently in the f.select field, I can choose a day name from the last 6 days and the value would be the actual date that is inserted into the DB. I don't see a way to select the day names as I currently am doing if I were to use f.datetime_select.